# How do I bypass ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_PRIVATE_YES?

Tags: accessibility, android-14

https://www.androidpolice.com/android-14-review/ says:

> In another attempt to limit the havoc false accessibility services can wreak, Google offers a new option for app developers to limit the visibility of their apps to disability-focused accessibility services only. This new option only allows accessibility services that are officially screened by Play Protect and the Play Store to see what you’re doing in potentially security-focused apps. Since malware and phishing software often use accessibility services to get around security features, this is a welcome change, even if it may break a few legitimate apps that rely on accessibility services in the process.

I don't need Google to protect me from myself. If I want to let a non-disability-focused accessibility service access an app that its developer doesn't, I should be able to since at the end of the day, it's my phone. How can I bypass this? I'm willing to do things that need ADB and/or root.

Answer (score 1):

I think the description fro AndroidPolice is a bit misleading. The one in [this blog](https://www.esper.io/blog/android-14-accessibility-security-feature) is better. Based on this information in my understanding this feature works this way:

`ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_PRIVATE_YES` is a security feature an app developer can enable for views in their app. The flag is a bit similar to `FLAG_SECURE` which disables screen shots of a view which has this flag set.

But `ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_PRIVATE_YES`
**disables that third party apps can remote control this view using accessibility services except from those third party apps which had been installed from Google Play Store** and thus are compliant to the usage rules Google has formulated for that apps should only use accessibility services to support disabled people.

That means this flag is not designed to protect you. An app developer can use it to protect their app (or parts of it) from automation tools without blocking really disabled people, which makes it an security feature.

Comment: But since it's my phone, I should be able to bypass it anyway. I'm asking how to do that.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica If it is a flag like `FLAG_SECURE` then you can hook the `setFlags` and `addFlags` method e.g. using an Xposed module or Frida and remove the flag. But at the moment I think this flag never made it into the final Android 14 release because I can not find any reference to it in the Android API documentation from Google, only [this page](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/u-beta1-incr/changes/android.view.View)  which tells me the flag was removed.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It may be possible that the flag was renamed to `ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_SENSITIVE_YES` Final Android API 34 knows  `ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_SENSITIVE_AUTO`, `ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_SENSITIVE_NO` and `ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_SENSITIVE_YES`.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#ACCESSIBILITY_DATA_SENSITIVE_AUTO